# How to use tojocky/node-printer in meteorJS app

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am trying to use [tojocky/node-printer](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer) library in meteorJS app.
I did following to install

```
meteor npm install --save node-printer
```

But when I try to use it, It doesnt seem to be working.

Following is my code snippet

```
import { printer } from 'node-printer';
import './mainLayout.html';

Template.mainLayout.helpers({
  printers: function() {
    return printer.getPrinters();
  }
});
```

I get following error

```
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPrinters' of undefined
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant use this module.
Its server only. 
It doesn't let you print from client browser.

Hope this helps anyone else trying to do this in future.